Vertically stacked ruby text elements
It is currently possible to stack multiple rt annotation elements vertically by using the now deprecated rtc element, or by nesting ruby elements, as given in the HTML standard §4.5.10 under the "Text with both phonetic and semantic annotations (double-sided ruby)" item.


<ruby>
  <ruby>
    <ruby>漢
      <rt>かん</rt>
    </ruby>
    <rt>한</rt>
  </ruby>
  <rt>hán</rt>
  <ruby>
    <ruby>字
      <rt>じ</rt>
    </ruby>
    <rt>자</rt>
  </ruby>
  <rt>tự</rt>
</ruby>



However, this can easily become unwieldy with multiple levels of nesting as can been seen in the example above. It would be more easily written without nesting, (closing </rt> tags omitted as allowed)


<ruby>
  漢 <rt>かん <rt>한 <rt>hán</rt>
  字 <rt>じ <rt>자 <rt>tự</rt>
</ruby>



This positions the rt elements horizontally and appears to be the expected behaviour, as noted under the same section in the standard,

If this results in two annotations covering the same single base segment, then the annotations can just be placed back to back.

Hence, I am trying to use the CSS3 ruby properties to position the rt elements vertically, but without success.


rt {
  display: ruby-text-container;
  ruby-position: over;
  ruby-align: center;
}
<ruby>
  漢 <rt>かん <rt>한 <rt>hán</rt>
  字 <rt>じ <rt>자 <rt>tự</rt>
</ruby>



Is there any way to achieve the same result using standard ruby facilities in HTML5+CSS3?
Edit: I tried display: table-row, which does have some effect on Chrome and Firefox -- the ruby elements are stacked vertically but to the right of the base, and it has no effect on Safari.


rt {
  display: table-row;
  ruby-position: over;
  ruby-align: center;
}
<ruby>
  漢 <rt>かん <rt>한 <rt>hán</rt>
  字 <rt>じ <rt>자 <rt>tự</rt>
</ruby>



